# Flux.concatMap going to next event before returning the result

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, concatmap

I have a Flux of test case objects, for each object, I need to call an external service, once a service response is received, in the next operation, it checks if the response is valid or not. But randomly for a few objects, before the response is received from the external service, Flux is releasing the signal.

```
Flux.fromIterable(masterTestCasesList).concatMap(tc -> iSandBoxRuleEngineClient.getRoutePlanResponseForTestCase(tc))
        .map(respObj -> {//checks if the response is matched.
            return result;}).collectList();
```

Expected Result :
1)Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_1.
2)Before calling the service for Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_1.
3)After hit : Resp generated; Ref id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_1.
4)Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_1 Is matched true.

1)Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_2.
2)Before calling the service for Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_2.
3)After hit : Resp generated; Ref id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_2.
4)Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_2 Is matched true.

1)Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_3.
2)Before calling the service for Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_3.
3)After hit : Resp generated; Ref id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_3.
4)Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_3 Is matched true.

Generated Output:

1)Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_1.
2)Before calling the service for Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_1.
3)After hit : Resp generated; Ref id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_1.
4)Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_1 Is matched true.

1)Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_2.
2)Before calling the service for Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_2.

1)Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_3.
2)Before calling the service for Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_3.
3)After hit : Resp generated; Ref id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_3.
4)Ref Id: 10002 TestCase : TESTCASE_3 Is matched true.

Comment: Before all external responses are received, onComplete signal is being released, which is causing the collectList() to create a mono of list. if 6 test cases are there, then collectList showing 4(random number) instead of 6.